# How to use install_github behind a proxy?

Tags: r, proxy, installation, devtools, httr

I've finally managed to make my proxy settings work for GitHub cloning, using the following code :

```
options(rsconnect.http = "internal")
Sys.setenv(http_proxy  = "http://proxy.lala.blabla:8080")
Sys.setenv(https_proxy = "https://proxy.lala.blabla:8080")
```

I can now clone github projects using File > New Project > Version control.

But I can't install from github :'(

```
require(devtools)
install_github("this/that")
--> Installation failed: Could not resolve host: raw.githubusercontent.com
```

People seem to use the following command :

```
http::set_config(use_proxy(...))
```

But that would force me to explicitely write my login / pass, which I don't want to do. I'd rather use the default ones that are associated to

```
options(rsconnect.http = "internal")
```

How can I configure the proxy here, without writing my login/pass please ?

Answer (score 1):

`devtools` uses `httr` under the hoods, see e.g. `devtools:::remote_package_name.github_remote` or `devtools:::remote_download.github_remote`.
That is why it requires you to set the proxy in the `httr::set_config(httr::use_proxy(...))` way.

I would suggest that you just pick up the information from the environment variables and pass the elements to `httr::set_config(httr::use_proxy(...))`. Then you don't need to type your settings in the code.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds great. I still have a hard time finding the right environment variable (I'm not good enough at Googling things apparently), so if you know where I can find it please feel free to share :)